# How precisely does ubuntu handle hotkeys

Tags: settings

I was wondering if anyone could tell me the locations of the relevant services/libraries/whatever ubuntu uses for hotkey management. I'm writing a gnome-shell extension at the moment because I'm sick of not having the compiz grid hotkeys and I wanted  to know how hotkeys are handled elsewhere in the distro, so I can check during install whether the hotkeys I'm using are already registered to another application (typically, they shouldn't be, but it pays to check).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this question still active?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,